# Transfer SQL Server Objects Task and Azure SQL - USE statement is not supported to switch between databases

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database

I am using SSIS package Transfer SQL Server Objects task in order to transfer some tables from local SQL Server database to Azure SQL.

My task fails with the following error "USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database."

I have read that this error occurs because master database is used and can be fixed by prefixing table names (for the tables to be transferred) with a database name. Unfortunately I cannot do that because when selecting table names there is no option to add database name as prefix - only schema name. So I am stuck here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer SQL Server Objects task is using SMO in the background, which then uses the "USE" statement. This makes Transfer SQL Objects incompatible for connecting to Azure SQL Database.

My recommendation is to use Azure SQL Data Sync if you are only synchronizing tables: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh456371.aspx

Let me know how you go with it.

Julie